# How to convert GenericList<T> to List<class>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to do some simulations in my code and for this i thought i would create a generic method where i can send in de desiered type i want returned. 
code:

```
private List<T> setSimulation<T>(Simulation simutlation, List<T> data)
{
    var model = (List<TrainAnnouncement>)data;


    return data;
}
```

At a certain point I need to call methods within this generic method.
All of these methods return a List of a specific class. My thought was that i could simply convert the data to the desiered list and call my method.

Sadly this does not work and I am wondering why? and How do i implement this correctly?

Comment: Why do you need a generic method if you actually expect `T` to be `TrainAnnouncement`?

Comment: Since I do not expect it to be TrainAnouncment every time. This is just one scenario

Comment: And what should your code do if `T` is not `TrainAnnouncement`? Ignore `model` variable, throw exception?

Comment: Well if it wasn't `TrainAnnouncement`, the cast would throw an exception (even if it otherwise worked, which of course it doesn't).

Comment: Note that the read/write _class_ `List<T>` is not covariant in `T`. If you can benefit from covariance, consider using the read-only _interface_ `IReadOnlyList<out T>` instead,

Comment: @MatthewWatson This cast will be disallowed at compile-time, i.e. you do not get any executable out of this, so there is nothing to raise an exception.

Comment: I did not implement the entire code here since I needed to solve the conversion problem only. 

The larger view of this is that my simulation parameter is a enum. I use a switch for this to know what conversion I need to make.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN Maybe a better solution would be to separate this login into different methods? Each of them would call some base method with common tasks.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I realise it won't compile, hence my comment "even if it otherwise worked, which of course it doesn't"

Comment: It is allowed to use `as`, as in: `var model = data as List<TrainAnnouncement>; if (data != null) { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead : `var model = data.Cast<TrainAnnoncement>().ToList();`

And here is some material about covariance and contravariance : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/